# Compare string to same column in multiple tables mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a string referring to a jpg file, let's say '**34563.jpg**'.
Now i want to know if this file is assigned to any record in this 3 tables.

All 3 tables has the same structure

```
id,name,img
```

My query just returns true to the first table:

```
SELECT clients_tbl.img, pets_tbl.img, places_tbl.img
FROM clients_tbl, pets_tbl, places_tbl
WHERE (clients_tbl.img = '34563.jpg')
OR (pets_tbl.img = '34563.jpg')
OR (places_tbl.img = '34563.jpg');
```

I need a boolean response from this query, it has been found or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `UNION`:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.*) when_not_found_0
FROM (
    SELECT img
    FROM clients_tbl
    WHERE clients_tbl.img = '34563.jpg'
  UNION
    SELECT img
    FROM pets_tbl
    WHERE pets_tbl.img = '34563.jpg'
  UNION
    SELECT img
    FROM places_tbl
    WHERE places_tbl.img = '34563.jpg'
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set aliases:

```
 SELECT clients_tbl.img as img_clients, pets_tbl.img as img_pets, places_tbl.img as img_places
```

And later turn the results to booleans.